# How to set up HTTP-based domain validation on nginx (how to reroute specifically one url to a text file)

Tags: nginx

I am having trouble redirecting properly.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.website.com website.com;

        location /.well-known/pki-validation/HASHHASH.txt {
           root /var/www/comodo;
        }
}
```

does not seem to work (can't find it). Any advice very much appreciated.

With HASHHASH.txt in /var/www/comodo

Answer (score 10):

The `root` directive constructs the pathname by concatenation, so the configuration in your question expects the file to be located at `/var/www/comodo/.well-known/pki-validation/HASHHASH.txt`.

You can use the `alias` directive:

```
location = /.well-known/pki-validation/HASHHASH.txt {
    alias /var/www/comodo/HASHHASH.txt;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put "" in the link:

```
location = "/.well-known/pki-validation/HASHHASH.txt" {
    alias /var/www/comodo/HASHHASH.txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the nginx sub-directories in `/usr/share/nginx`...

```
location = /.well-known/pki-validation/HASHHASH.txt {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/HASHHASH.txt;
}
```